# pass value from HTML to TS from an ngFor Angular

Tags: angular

I have this HTML with value i am getting from an Array in my Component

```
//myComponent.html
   <p class="m_a"> 
       <a routerLink="informe" class="nav-link px-sm-0 px-2">
          <strong>{{info.resolucion}} | {{info.ano}}</strong> 
       {{info.titulo}}
       </a>
    </p>
```

But I want to get value of selected item and pass to the component.ts, but the problem is that i got the values from this function

```
//myComponent.ts
showNodes() {
this.loader = true;
this.buscadorService.getNodes()
  .subscribe((data: InformesCounter) => {
    this.loader = false;
    this.data = data;
    this.informesNode = data.data;
    this.nid = this.informesNode.map((data: { id: any;}) => data.id);
    this.nodeList = this.informesNode.map((data: { attributes:any;}) => data.attributes);
  });
}
```

But i do not want to get the entire array, i only want to get the title/titulo i selected from the HTML so i can pass it to the component or another component. AFAIK it's possible to do with two-way databinding, but couldn't get it to work.

Ex: i want to retrieve the info.titulo of clicked item and console.log in ts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use the button instead and use the (click) to pass the value to component's class from the template:

```html
<button (click)="navigate(info.titulo)">
  <strong>{{info.resolucion}} | {{info.ano}}</strong> 
  {{info.titulo}}
</button>
```

then in component:

```js
navigate(titulo){
   console.log(titulo);
   this.router.navigate(['informe']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the answer you provided was of great help to start with but i cannot change the HTML/SASS so i just adapted it to my code.